# Assistance with customizing a CakePHP Form

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I am displaying a form in the following manner:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('AmazonMatches', array('action' => 'selectMatches'));
echo $this->Form->input('option_id', array('options' => $allAmazonMatches, 'type' => 'radio'));
echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));
?>

$allAmazonMatches = Array ( [1] => B002I0HJZO [2] => B002I0HJzz [3] => B002I0HJccccccccc )
```

Right now the form shows up with radio buttons next to the text "B002I0HJZO" etc etc

What I want to do is to show the radio button next to a URL like

```
http://somewebsite/B002I0HJZO
```

How do I prepend a URL to the radio option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `$allAmazonMatches` in controller

```
$allAmazonMatches = $this->Model->find('list');
foreach($allAmazonMatches as $k => $v) {
    $allAmazonMatches[$k] = 'http://somewebsite/' . $v;
}
```